# java backed webscript alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, web-scripting

error: "package org.springframework.extensions.webscripts does not exist" for all the below imports

code:

```
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptRequest;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptResponse;

public class Test1 extends AbstractWebScript{
public void execute(WebScriptRequest req, WebScriptResponse res){
String name = "World from Java";  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the relevant classes in your classpath. If you're using maven, add the following to your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.extensions.surf</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webscripts</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```